# to print the output prescribed

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int q,a,b,i,number;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        int a[b];
        int number=1;
        for(i=0;i<b;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                a[i]=number;
                number++;
            }

            a[i]=number;
            if(number>0)
            number=number*-1;
        }
    }
}
/*the above code i tried a little bit , but it's incomplete and may be incorrect too, you may help
i want to print the sequence as 1,2,-2,3,-3,3,4,-4,4,-4,5,-5,5,-5,5..... till n , where n is size of array in c++?*/
```

Chef's kid, Junior chef loves playing with different series. Chef, impressed by his son's curiosity, gifts him a special series S on his birthday
S=1,2,-2,3,-3,3,4,-4,4,-4,.............
Now chef, eager to check the intelligence of his son, gives him q queries to solve. Each query consists of two positions a and b, and Junior_chef is required to calculate the sum of all integers from a to b.
Input

The first line of the input contains a single integer q, which denotes the number of queries. Next q lines consist of two integers, a and b.
Output

Print the answer in single line.
Constraints

1<=q<=10 , 1<=a,b<=10^12
Sample Input

1
1 4
Sample Output

4
Explanation : As the series is 1,2,-2,3, therefore the sum will be 4.

Comment: for the readers , please don't be confused , kindly don't read the whole my question , my question is just a little bit on this comment only , how to print  1,2,-2,3,-3,3,4,-4,4,-4,............. in c++ .

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: "my question is just a little bit on this comment only" - so why not write the question in the form of a question, so we don't need to read every last detail of the code to figure out what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( n <= 0 ) break;

        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) std::cout << ( j % 2 ? -i : i ) << ' ';
        }

        std::endl( std::cout );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter sequentially 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 then the output will be

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1
1 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 2
1 2 -2 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 3
1 2 -2 3 -3 3 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 4
1 2 -2 3 -3 3 4 -4 4 -4 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 5
1 2 -2 3 -3 3 4 -4 4 -4 5 -5 5 -5 5 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 6
1 2 -2 3 -3 3 4 -4 4 -4 5 -5 5 -5 5 6 -6 6 -6 6 -6 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 7
1 2 -2 3 -3 3 4 -4 4 -4 5 -5 5 -5 5 6 -6 6 -6 6 -6 7 -7 7 -7 7 -7 7 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```

Comment: why using `while(true){ /*..stuff..*/ if(n <= 0) break; }` instead of `do{ /*stuff*/}while(n > 0);`?

Comment: @Alejandro Díaz  What will be the stuff in this case?

Comment: Same, just that the `n` variable would be declared outside the loop, more of a coding style observation than anything else.

Comment: @Alejandro Díaz  Are you going two times check whether n > 0?

Comment: @Kapil Arora If so then mark my answer as the best because it is the only answer.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no, just once http://ideone.com/ghsv17

Comment: @Alejandro Díaz  I am sure that this code only confuses the reader. It is simply a bad code.

Comment: Why is it bad? It's exactly the same but using the loop's condition instead of an additional `if`

Comment: @Alejandro Díaz  It is what differs a good programmer from a bad programmer. The condition is placed in the wrong point. Now reader shall investigate allcode between the point where the value was entered and the end of the loop that to be sure that this value is not used when it is non-poistive.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I guess that makes sense for any non-trivial loop, point taken, thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro Díaz You always should select a general approach. In this case the code will not be rewritten if some changes are required to make.